# How do I start for IT governance for the portfolio of applications of our business unit?

Tags: project-governance

In our business unit we have a number of software applications developed during the last 10 years.
I'm in the organization since 2 years, and I've been trying to setup a new team in the business unit from scratch and the team should take care of those applications.

My boss is asking me to be the responsible of IT governance. While I have a rough and shallow understanding of what that is, I've no clue where to start, considering also that the company is pretty big and has its own governance processes.

The company gave us an IT and Business ownership of those applications, but I could hardly understand what that means: a part from calling us when there are troubles.